# Как спрятать в Visual Studio окно свойств и панель элементов, когда активен редактор кода?

Tags: visual-studio

Почему то в Visual Studio, применяется один макет окон, когда активно окно в режиме конструктора и когда активно окно в режиме кода. Причины наверно есть, ведь можно и одновременно открыть на части экрана и то и то... Но я такой возможностью не пользуюсь и мне не удобно, что часть экрана когда я пишу код занимают окна свойств и панель элементов, которые мне нужны, когда я пользуюсь конструктором. Возможно ли настроить студию так, чтобы автоматически скрывать их, когда у меня активно окно с кодом, и автоматически отображать, когда активно окно конструктора?

P.S. У меня версия 2008, ответ ищется для неё. Но прошу также оставлять ответы для любой версии.

Comment: Это можно сделать с помощью макросов. Смотрите [этот](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1139710/5045688) вопрос. В более новых версиях VS макросов уже нет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Спасибо! вроде то что нужно, но не могу заставить работать. Что нужно сделать? копирую код в модуль EnvironmentEvents моего проекта макросов MyMacros. А дальше что? Если, как вызывать какой-нибудь SUB я разобрался, то тут не понятно скопировал, сохранил, даже построить нажал, закрыл-открыл студию. И вроде ничего не происходит, брейкпоинт ставил в обработчик, не попадаю. Как его заставить работать?

Comment: Пишете код - можете просто нажать Shift+Alt+Enter - перейдёте в полноэкранный режим. Это не дословно то, что вы просите, но очень удобно. Не помню, работало ли в 2008 студии (под рукой нет), в 2015 точно работает. Вроде это не решарперный хоткей, а самой студии. Если у вас много мониторов -- то развернёт на полный экран текущего монитора.

Comment: @AK, ну как не дословно! панель элементов и окно свойств пропадают, а обозреватель решения остаётся в пин-состоянии. Это ровно, то что мне нужно было, Вы решили мою проблему. Пожалуйста опубликуйте Ваш комментарий, как ответ

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот такой ещё вариант: нажимать `Shift+Alt+Enter`, когда вы переходите в режим правки кода.

Это стандартный студийный хоткей `View.FullScreen`.

Под рукой студия 2015, проверил у коллег в 2012 и 2010 — работает. 2008 под рукой нет, но думаю, что тоже сработает.

Comment: да в 2008 работает. Галочку точно вам, а вот для баунти сложный выбор, все ответы хороши))

Comment: Конкурс подошел к концу. Этот ответ, не позволяет автоматически скрывать ненужные окна, но 1) он единственный, который мне подошел 2) набрал больше голосов к моменту завершения 3) очень прост в реализации, вообще ничего не надо делать 4) подходит ко всем версиям студии 5) получает баунти

Comment: @3per Пользуйтесь на здоровье. Вообще, не ожидал, что такой простой рецепт подойдёт, сначала даже комментарий не хотел делать.

Answer (score 7):

> Но прошу также оставлять ответы для любой версии

Начиная с версии `Visual Studio “14” CTP 2`: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2014/07/08/visual-studio-14-ctp-2-available/ появилась возможность сохранять разметку открытых окон в IDE.

Как это сделать описано здесь: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4k7zyeba.aspx

Если кратко, то расставляешь окна как тебе удобно и в верхнем меню выбираешь `Window > Save Window Layout`. Потом расставляешь окна по-другому как нужно и сохраняешь еще одну разметку. Переключение между разметками с помощью сочетания клавиш: `CTRL + ALT + 1..0`

Видео-инструкция: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZ4LDZU7c_s

Единственный минус - данная фича отсутствует в Visual Studio 2008

Answer (score 3):

В Visual Studio 2005/2008 скрывать и показывать окна и панели можно с помощью макросов. Смотрите [этот](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4926282/5045688) ответ. К сожалению, в данный момент у меня нет доступа к предыдущим версиям VS, а в новых версиях макросы отсутствуют.

Устанавливать ненужную мне версию Студии я не горю желанием, однако я установил расширение [Visual Commander](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/deda8ac1-75e6-4068-89ab-b607cee38f2d) (доступно для версий 2010-2015; невозможно установить в Express-версии). Опробовал на VS2015 Community.

После его установки и перезапуска Студии в меню появится пункт VCmd. Выбираем пункт Extensions, добавляем новое расширение, даём ему подходящее название (HideToolboxAndPropertiesPanes), выбираем язык C# v4.0 и вводим следующий код:

```
using EnvDTE;
using EnvDTE80;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;

public class E : VisualCommanderExt.IExtension
{
    public void SetSite(DTE2 DTE, Package package)
    {
        dte = DTE;
        windowEvents = DTE.Events.WindowEvents;
        windowEvents.WindowActivated += OnWindowActivated;
    }
    public void Close()
    {
        windowEvents.WindowActivated -= OnWindowActivated;
    }
    private void OnWindowActivated(Window gotFocus, Window lostFocus)
    {
        if (gotFocus.Caption.EndsWith(" [Design]"))
        {
            dte.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindProperties).AutoHides = false;
            dte.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindToolbox).AutoHides = false;
        }
        else
        {
            dte.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindProperties).AutoHides = true;
            dte.Windows.Item(Constants.vsWindowKindToolbox).AutoHides = true;
        }
    }
    private DTE2 dte;
    private WindowEvents windowEvents;
}
```

Щёлкаем по кнопкам Compile, Install. Готово! Наш макрос-расширение установлен. Теперь окна Properties и Toolbox автоматически показываются, когда активен документ, содержащий строку `[Design]` в названии и скрываются во всех остальных случаях.